# People I manage earn more than me, how to approach this with my bosses

Tags: management, salary, company-culture

I was promoted a year ago as a manager. I was given the job without seeing the job spec or knowing what the salary was, but I really wanted the position so I took it without questioning my boss. I should say, my boss doesn’t believe in job specs so even when I asked he said he couldn’t give me one.

Once I got the job, I was told I was going to earn 300 euros more per month (which isn’t much) and my boss also dissolved the team I was supposed to manage. This meant I now had quadruple the work because I need to deal with each employee's requests instead of having them go to their manager. To add insult to injury, my boss put me in the same office as my former manager (there are now two managers with the same title). She is super old and barely knows how to use a computer, which means I end up doing her job daily while she huffs and puffs and complains about how much she has to do. Here’s the question: I saw the contract of a new exec we’re hiring and she’s going to earn more than I. I will manage her, I have much more responsibility than she, I have to stay in the office until late, yet she will earn more than I.

I’ve spoken to HR about this, but they’re not doing anything about it. What should I do? My current boss is leaving and said my salary would be revised at the end of the year, but he doesn’t seem to care anymore.

Comment: You already asked the two-in-office in a past question ([this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/191744/73791)) why repeat this here?

Comment: And, unfortunately, the salary difference probably means that you could have negotiated it higher (but didnt) and that this new hire *did* negotiate it higher and got it...

Comment: have you considered that you are the coach but the worker is Lebron?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, there were four middle leaders bellow me, those leaders managed around 30 people, now instead of managing 4 people, I manage 34. Everyone comes to me.

Answer (score 11):

OK, you have multiple problems, and you appear to be conflating them as a single problem.

Let's break them down:

- Your role is very undefined, and I'm going to infer that means your authority is very undefined, as well.
- You are doing the work of your coworker who is either unable or unwilling to do her work.
- You have more duties than your workday permits to get accomplished.
- You are underpaid.

Each of these is a separate problem and needs to be addressed separately.

- Undefined role:  Does your company have an HR department? Speak with them. You need to insist on a concrete job description. You can couch it as: "How can I know whether or not I am succeeding if it's not clear what my responsibilities and deliverables are?" If your boss is retiring soon, has rebuffed your request, and is not engaging, then escalation to a higher authority is appropriate.
- Stop doing the work of your coworker. Unless her work has been assigned to you, just stop. If the work doesn't get completed, that is on her, not you. You are enabling her behavior. I liken this to the people who weigh 500# and can't stand up. Someone keeps bringing them unhealthy food, and THAT person is being just as big a part of the problem.
- After you address the previous issue, I would be interested in whether or not you *DO* have time for your own duties during the workday.  If you do not, then ask for mentoring or training in how to accomplish your workload more efficiently. Your superiors may not be aware of your workload's demands, or they may be waiting for you to figure the above issue out on your own.
- As for your pay: You need to do the legwork. Find at least half a dozen equivalent job openings on the recruiting boards and what their offered rates are, as well as documenting how you are qualified for and performing at that level. No business voluntarily increases expenses. You have to demonstrate that it is more cost-effective to retain you at market rates than it is to recruit and pay a replacement.

This may sound "harsh," but you are in a business relationship, not a social one. Every day is a negotiation of terms: How much skill and effort are you providing and how much are they compensating you for that? Don't accept "their" timeline on when your pay will be reviewed. If you are not satisfied with what you are being offered, then you need to either stand up for yourself, including finding other employment if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Management is NOT always worth more to the company than actually doing the productive work. This is not a particularly unusual situation. If you are doing technical leadership, the answer may be somewhat different, but if you're just a "people manager", well... that's a fungible commodity.

Salaries are generally reviewed on a fixed schedule. Griping now probably is just as useless as you've been told. Instead, ask your own manager what they would need to see from you to justify giving you a raise at that time, and then do your best to deliver on that. You may still not get the raise, but trying to go around the system is generally less effective than working with it.

Comment: I’ve been doing the job for the past year, they said we’d have a review this year but they keep stalling me so it’s been quite hard to have a conversation with them about a salary increase.

Comment: See "fixed schedule". If it's anything but the smallest company, salary changes happen only on the company's schedule. If that schedule is with the new year, all they _can_ do is tell you they'll consider it. I say again, ask your manager how to help justify your raise when the time comes.